# Stripe Node.js - How to split a payment between several beneficiaries (connected accounts)?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

For my first implementation, I transfer the amount of the transaction directly to a beneficiary from a paymentMethod Id retrieved from my app (Flutter). Now my goal would be to split the payment between several beneficiaries on the same transaction.

**First implementation code:**

```
var clonedPaymentMethod = await stripe.paymentMethods.create(
        {
          payment_method: paym,
        },
        {
          stripeAccount: stripeVendorAccount,
        }
      );

var paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
          {
            amount: amount,
            currency: currency,
            payment_method: clonedPaymentMethod.id,
            confirmation_method: "automatic",
            confirm: true,
            application_fee_amount: fee,
            description: "desc",
          },
          {
            stripeAccount: stripeVendorAccount,
          }
        );
const paymentIntentReference = paymentIntent;
```

By checking the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers), I noticed that the `stripe.paymentMethods.create` method was no longer specified, and that the `stripe.transfers.create` methods were added.

Answer (score 1):

This code is attempting to clone a payment method to a connected account and then create a direct charge on that account. In order to create charges and then to split the funds of that charge to separate connected accounts a different approach would be needed. The model would be closer to "Separate charges and transfers", where the charge is made on that platform and then some amounts are shared among the connected accounts using transfers. A full description is outlined here [1].

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers

Comment: I followed the documentation, but I get the following error: StripeInvalidRequestError: Insufficient funds in Stripe account. I also set my account to manuals payout.

Comment: If using express or custom accounts (recommended for separate charges and transfers), it could be that there is not enough available balance on the platform to fulfil the transfers. Adding funds to the available balance with a special card might work. https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses or look into setting the "source transaction" attribute which binds a transfer to a charge on the platform to guarantee funds, https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#transfer-availability